# Android with SDL compatibility

Tags: java, android, compatibility

I don't know if this is the right place to ask about that, but I'm looking for a good start with programming on Android. I've completed few tutorials, but now I would like to train myself with the SDL Library.
I've seen on forums and websites that SDL and android are compatible, but I didn't see how, does anyone could help me on that ? A good link ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find a description of how to use the official SDL Android port here:

http://www.libsdl.org/tmp/SDL/README.android

Comment: Since I've posted I found this page ! But thanks, I've started to have fun from there ^^